# Compare 2 Columns and insert value of 3rd column in to 4th if they match in excel

Tags: excel

Column A got about 20k values Column B got about 200 C got 20k.
Now i want to check if a value of A is found inside of B if yes it should take the value of C in the same row and put it in to D.

So basicly if( Ax=By){Dy=Cx} if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paste this to `D1` and copy it down:

`=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,$B:$B,1,FALSE)),"",C1)`

Testing:

[image]

**Update:**

`=VLOOKUP(B1,$A:$C,3,FALSE)`

[image]

Comment: are u sure that this is correct cause as soon as i try to paste it, it throws an error on me

Comment: figured out why it didnt work seems like the commands are slightly diffrent in german excel. anyway this still is the wrong answer.because the way u did it the D only gets put in the same row the A is i need it in the same row where B is . so if we take your example the d would need to be in the 2nd row.

Comment: See updated version, which is a simple `vlookup`. It would help if you provide sample input and expected output in your question.

Comment: guess it would have been alot easier sry for that. and thanks alot for the answer worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Put this in D1 and fill down:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP(A1;B:B;1;0);B:C;2;0);"")
```